# Mounting an 18.04 drive in a 20.04 install without reformatting it

Tags: mount

I have two 4tb HDD's that are formatted using 18.04 that are loaded up with movies that I'm trying to use in a fresh 20.04 installation. The drives appear in 20.04 but the mount options that I'm used to seeing in the 18.04 disk manager are missing in the 20.04 one. It wants me to do a reformat. I don't want to reformat my movies away just to get the drives to mount. What's the fix?

Comment: "*I can't seem to mount them*" is vague -- it could mean almost anything. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1336973/edit) to clearly explain exactly what you are trying, and show us complete error messages indicating failure.

Comment: You certainly do NOT have to reformat the drives but your question is still a little light on details. Do you know the device names, sda, sdb etc? do you known how they were partitioned. If you run this command and post the output it might provide a starting point. lsblk Then we could try to mount them manually, when that works we can add them to the /etc/fstab file and have them mounted at boot for you.